# React-router urls don't match using Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, express, reactjs, react-router, mod-proxy

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy in Apache to serve up a React/Redux/webpack bundle. I have an Express server file serving my static files and index.html as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('./dist'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

My apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass "/foo/" "http://localhost:8777/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/foo/" "http://localhost:8777/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when navigating to example.com/foo, my index.html and webpack bundle are served up properly, but React router throws an error saying that `/foo/` did not match any routes. Obviously, this is because `/foo` is the proxied location for that app, and react router doesn't (and should not have to) account for the proxy path used in production.

How do I setup Apache so that when the request is sent to `localhost:8777`, the `/foo` path is not passed by apache? In other words, how do you setup the proxypass so that a request to `example.com/foo/bar` is transformed to a request to `localhost:8777/bar` on the server, then returned to the client as if it came from example.com/foo/bar?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Curious to know if you ever found a good solution, tayden?

Comment: @MattSidor I never really did. I ended up changing my react router urls to include the proxy location so that the pages would render as expected. I'd still be happy to find a better solution

Comment: Does this solve your problem?
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570841/proxy-react-server-behind-apache/48964874#48964874](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570841/proxy-react-server-behind-apache/48964874#48964874)

Answer (score 0):

My team had a similar issue, and the way they've resolved it was by using a RewriteRule with a forced redirect [R] before letting Apache Proxy pass catch it off. So perhaps you could try it out:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests off
  RewriteRule ^/foo/bar/& /bar/ [R]
  ProxyPass "/bar/" "http://localhost:8777/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/bar/" "http://localhost:8777/"
</VirtualHost>`

I am not an expert on Apache configurations, so you might have to play around with the RewriteRule a bit yourself (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). However, I believe the above could potentially be an answer to only a part of your question:

> how do you setup the proxypass so that a request to example.com/foo/bar is transformed to a request to localhost:8777/bar on the server

But I am not too sure about this, sorry:

> then returned to the client as if it came from example.com/foo/bar?

Hope some of it could help.

Answer (score 0):

change nginx server more flexible and easy config

```
server { 
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/web;
  location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
}
```