# Proxy react server behind Apache

Tags: reactjs

I've just created a react app using create-react-app and the app start at port 3000, fine. I'd like to access the app with a prefix, in my case /node and in port 80, i.e. http://localhost/node. For that i've configured apache with:

```
<Location /node>
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
```

And works partially, i can access the http://localhost/node, but the page don't load correctly because the route to bundle is static. Usign the console i see the request http://localhost/static/js/bundle.js fails with not found.

bundle.js is not in index.html, so it should be injected by webpack.

I've been looking around where to config webpack to change the configuration to put bundle.js under node/static/js/bundle.js or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I generated build folder by running

```
sudo npm run build
```

in the app root folder. Then I created folder /var/www/html/app and copied index.html and related files to the folder. I also had to correct the file paths in index.html.

Then the react app can be opened by going to url http://localhost/app.

Answer (score 0):

How to not use apache proxy.

Edit "package.json",  add

```
"homepage": "http://localhost/" ,
```

Not `"homepage": "http://localhost/node"`

Result:

```
$ head package.json
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://localhost/",
  "devDependencies": {
....
```

Run

```
npm run build
```

Create symbolic link

```
ln -s create-react-app/build /var/www/html/node
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem, I solved using Webpack's `publicPath` property: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

In my configuration, I bound such property to an environment variable:

```
 output: {
   path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
   publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_URL || '/',
 }
```

In your case, you'll run something like `PUBLIC_URL=/node npm run build`. This will make Webpack prepend `/node` to every url in `index.html`.